# Self-study - Numerical Optimization

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics, numerical-optimization

Is there any available online course on Numerical Optimization other than NPTEL courses?

I'm also looking for lecture notes or textbooks that are suitable for self-study with lots of examples and conceptual comments.

Thanks for your time.